# How do I add ajax URL on a laravel js file?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a store locator for a website that I am building in Laravel. Since the blade file calls the js file tht is on the assests folder. It doesn't recognize the URL like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ URL::action('getLocation') }}',
    // ...
});
```

This is how I have my route.php

```
Route::post('/getLocation', array('as'=>'getLocation','uses'=>'FrontController@getLocation'));
```

So it doesn't find the file. How can I call this function in the ajax URL?

Comment: What actually gets printed out in the JS?  i.e. what is `{{ URL::action('getLocation') }}`

Comment: @ExplosionPills it gets the current latitud and longitud from the user

Comment: Is this a `php` file or a `js` file (where you used `$.ajax`) ?

Comment: Is the file that contains the $.ajax request a .blade.php file?

Comment: The js file is called by the blade file

Comment: Which file contains `$.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::action('getLocation') }}'` ?

Comment: The ajax I am calling it or using it in the js file

Comment: geolocation.js contains the $.ajax

Comment: Do you have a `blade master layout` ?

Comment: Yes I do. But since I want to keep my js files separated from the blade files. I call the js files on my blade files

Comment: @Monica if your ajax function called from a .js file, try to change '{{ URL::action('getLocation') }}' to '/getLocation' and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a demonstration of how i would achieve this

> I might be late here. This is just a **sample code** to help understand people
>   who visit this question. Hope this helps anyone who visits here.

in my **routes.php** i define a named route

```
Route::post('getLocation',array(
    'as'=>'getLocation','uses'=>'FrontController@getLocation')
);
```

added name route as data-url in my **somehtmlform.blade.php** file

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
{!! Form::text('input-name',null,array('class'=>'form-control search-input','data-url'=> URL::route("getLocation") ))
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

my **search.js** file catches the data-url and use it as post url

```
$('.search-input').each(function(){
  $(this).on('change',function (e) {
      search(this)
  });
});

function search(self) {
    var query = $(self).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(self).attr('data-url'),
        type: 'post',
        data: {'q':query, '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);        
        },
        error: function(data){
            // Not found
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
// Add this in your filtes.php file (feel free to store where you like)
View::composer('layouts.master', function($view) {
    $ajaxUrl = json_encode(array('url' => URL::action('getLocation')));
    $view->with('ajax', $ajaxUrl);
});
```

Add this in you `master.blade.php` file's (`master layout`) `<head></head>` section (place it before your `js` file):

```
<script>var ajax = {{ $ajax or 'undefined' }}</script>
```

Now you can use this as:

```
// ajax.url
console.log(ajax.url);
```

Read here, [similar thing.](http://heera.it/laravel-pass-user-object-javascript-object)

Comment: Did you write `<script>var ajax = {{ $ajax or 'undefined' }}</script>` before your `js` file in the `head`, maybe you should put it at the top inside `<head>`. It works and tested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the wrong method for generating the URL.
Try switching from `URL::action()` to `URL::route()`.

`URL::action()` is used to generate a URL to a given controller action, but then you need to write it like this:

```
URL::action('FrontController@getLocation')
```

URL::route() generates a url to a route which is named in the route definition, using "as" => "routeName". In your case:

```
URL::route('getLocation')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! but the problem is that since the js is not on the blade file I cant use the blade functions

Comment: Oh ok. Now I get it. I normally set up my JS so that I can pass some settings to the given feature. In this case I'd wrap that ajax call in a JS function, e.g. var getLocation = function(settings){} and then from within my (Blade) view I'd call that function with the needed parameter: <script>getLocation({ajaxUrl: {{URL::route('getLocation'}})});</script> (Sorry, sitting in a hotel bar, code untested, hope you get the point :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you call your ajax function from a .js file,
try to change the blade part `'{{ URL::action('getLocation') }}'` to `'/getLocation'`
or pass a full url like: `'http://domain.com/getLocation'` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

in js file, you can't not use the Url::action for route
just do

```js
url:"/getLocation"
```